# DocumentReference.set(Object o) changes boolean field names

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

When using `DocumentReference.set(object)`, boolean fields are changed. Fields with 'is' prefix get changed to normal field value

```
class Invitation {
    private boolean isRequested;
    private boolean isValid;
    private boolean isAccepted;
    private String lastName,firstName;
    private long sentOn;
}
```

And when I push this object to the database using `set()` method the boolean values are changed in this way:

[image: Firestore screenshot]

Comment: I am using Android

Comment: You must be passing dummy data .!

Comment: no i am creating a class of invitation and pushing it via set methiod

Comment: you are pushing null value.? or it always replace same object.?

Comment: few of them are not being initialized which will be updated later using update method

Comment: Could you plz post your method so will be able to help.!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158947/discussion-between-atif-abbasi-and-mahi-tej-gvp).

Comment: wish I saw your answer earlier on, this ruined my entire Sunday tinkering with it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an automatic translation so the getter can be named `isBoolean` rather than `getBoolean`.

In Android, you can use the [`@PropertyName` annotation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/PropertyName) to rename a property, which will allow you to specify a different name (in this instance, the exact name), which Firebase should use as is:

```
class Invitation {
    private boolean isRequested;

    @PropertyName(value="isRequested")
    public boolean isRequested() {
        return this.isRequested;
    }

    @PropertyName(value="isRequested")
    public void setRequested(boolean value) {
        this.isRequested = value;
    }

    // ...
}
```

---

However, I would suggest dropping the `is` prefix on the field names and instead only using it for the getter, like:

```
public boolean isRequested() {
    return this.requested;
}
```

Comment: See my edit, you actually need to specify the `@PropertyName` annotation on the getters & setters, not the field.

Comment: sorry my bad was using it to a field value

Comment: Why can't the property name and getter be the same?

Answer (score 2):

In Kotlin, use `@field:JvmField`. For example,

```
data class User(
    @field:JvmField
    val isEnrolled: Boolean = false
)
```

Answer (score 1):

We experienced this issue and we solved like this.

```
boolean isPrimary;

public boolean getIsPrimary() {
    return this.isPrimary;
}

public void setIsPrimary(boolean isPrimary) {
    this.isPrimary = isPrimary;
}
```

I know it's weird. It seems Firestore uses the 'getter' method to set object,
because I first changed the 'setter' method and nothing happened. And I changed 'getter' method and it finally worked correctly.

I hope they fix this issue. Because nobody uses the 'getter' method for boolean as 'getIsSomething' in Android.

Comment: *Because nobody uses the 'getter' method for boolean as 'getIsSomething' in Android.* While this is true, the idea is that the field should be named `something` and the getter should be `isSomething()`, then there is no need to use `getIsSomething()`. There's no need to have the `is` prefix on the private field name.

Comment: @Grimthorr You're right. Generally the naming convention for boolean value in Java is same as what you said. But Firebase is a cross platform framework. In Javascript, The naming convention as `isSomething` is more common. And our service is also not only for Android. And my thinking is it is not good idea if some 3rd party framework enforce specific naming convention.